# Qual IDE tem suporte ao PHP 7?

Tags: ide, php-7

Alguém conhece algum IDE (ou editor de código mais simples) com suporte ao PHP 7?

Eu utilizo o NetBeans, mas parece que o suporte ao PHP 7 nele poderá ser adicionado em versões futuras, mas ainda é incerto isso.

Procuro por uma IDE ou editor de códigos que tenha complementação de código PHP 7 e que busque nomes de variáveis, métodos, funções, classes, etc, nos arquivos do projeto, semelhante ao NetBeans. Alguém conhece algum, de preferência grátis?

Comment: [phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuo usando Netbeans para muitos projetos, atualmente ele pertence a Apache Foundation, o projeto continua sendo atualizado constantemente.
Novo link: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/

> Atualmente estou usando o Netbeans 8.2 Ele vem com suporte ao PHP7.
> Você pode baixar a versão somente para PHP ou a All que já vem com
> tudo embutido.  https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: Agora saiu o NetBeans 8.2 e já estou usando :)

Answer (score 9):

Algumas das novidades do PHP7

- Classes anônimas.
- Declaração de tipos retorno.
- Operador null coalesce (`??`)
- Operador spaceshipe (`<=>`)

O [PHPStorm 10](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/) tem surporte a sintaxe do PHP7 é uma IDE paga. Uma opção sem custo é o [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) no entanto é necessário uma configuração adiciona.

Para habilitar o suporte ao PHP7 `window>preference` no treeview do lado direito vá em `PHP>Interpreter` escolha a opção PHP7 e dê ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]