# Quais IDEs possuem suporte para a linguagem Hack?

Tags: ide, hack

Alguém tem conhecimento de alguma IDE para a [linguagem Hack](http://hacklang.org)?

Existe algum ***plugin*** disponível para as IDEs como Eclipse, Netbeans, etc.?

Atualmente estou criando o código no PhpStorm mas ele não entende a maioria das declarações (como tipagem de atributos de classe) e assim fica difícil programar.

Comment: Favor, reabrira a pergunta. Ela está dentro do escopo do site. Pergunta similar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112262/57801

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fui [no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23582444/221800) pra ver. Não está muito atualizado, mas lá diz

- [Vim](https://github.com/hhvm/vim-hack)
- [Emacs](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/tree/master/hphp/hack/editor-plugins/emacs)
- [Sublime](https://github.com/SiebelsTim/hack-sublime)
- [Atom](https://github.com/steelbrain/atom-hack)
- [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/docs/languages/hack/)

[PHPStorm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/06/hack-language-support-in-phpstorm-postponed/) deverá ter suporte eventualmente, e pode ser a melhor opção pouco tempo depois.